# Is there any way to use wildcards in PhraseExpress?

Tags: phraseexpress

I am using PhraseExpress v10.1.59d. Suppose I want the following:

```
### Introduction ###
```

to be replaced with:

```
<h3>Introduction</h3>
```

How do I capture the text between the prefix and postfix (i.e., Introduction)? What would the **Autotext** and **Phrase content** fields need to be? I don't want to prompt the user for input. Do I have to use variables? Or is there some simpler way? Something like:

```
Autotext: ### [*] ###
Phrase content: <h3>[*]</h3>
```

Comment: why is input out of the question, if I may ask? I've posted a possible solution below.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use wildcards except for numbers.

**Cursor macro**

For this case I would recommend the `{#cursor}` macro.

- Title: `Heading 3 HTML` (or something else)
- Content: `<h3>{#cursor}</h3>`
- Autotext: `,h3`

After typing `,h3`, the cursor will be between the tags. Type your text, then press <kbd>end</kbd>.

This has the advantage that you can set your own trigger. Disadvantage: you have to create a phrase for every case.

**Autotext macro**

If you want to put everything in one phrase and don't need a special trigger character like the comma above, you may want to use the `{#autotext}` macro in addition to the `{#cursor}` macro.

- Title: `HTML tags` (or something else)
- Content: `<{#autotext}>{#cursor}</{#autotext}>`
- Autotext: `h1|h2|h3` (add what you want here, but separate with a vertical line)

Answer (score -1):

Work with `{#autotext}` which inserts the triggering Autotext.